# Using ironscheme in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, scheme, ironscheme

Though it says on the IronScheme codeplex site that a plugin is included for visual studio, I have no idea how to get ironscheme working with VS...

Is it possible? If so , how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you definitely need Visual Studio 2008 SP1, without SP1 it will [cause problems](http://ironscheme.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=50805).

Secondly, follow the instructions in the [visual-studio.txt](https://ironscheme.svn.codeplex.com/svn/IronScheme/IronScheme.Console/docs/visual-studio.txt) file.

Run from the command line:

1. If admin: RegPkg /codebase <absolute path of IronScheme.VisualStudio.dll>
2. If not admin: RegPkg /ranu /codebase <absolute path of IronScheme.VisualStudio.dll>
3. devenv /setup

Now start VS, and open a file with a 'ss' or 'sls' or 'scm' extension.

Cheers

leppie